# Unsupported get request. Please read the Graph API documentation only with variable

Tags: php, graph, facebook-php-sdk

I have this simple code, where I'm trying to access a page with an ID. Whenever I run this code, I get an error "Unsupported get request. Please read the Graph API documentation"

```
$leheid = $page['accounts'][$x]['id'];
try {
    $page = $fb->get("$leheid?fields=events", $at);
    $page = $page->getGraphPage();
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Okay, but whenever I run the same code without a variable and with a string, no errors...

If I echo or print the same variable I get the right string with no spaces or anything else in there, so I'm quite confused...

Also, I tried $leheid. '....'

Answer (score 1):

It's an old question but i would like to contribute and maybe help someone else with the same problem.

The reason why the code above didn't work, was because i mistyped the API response function

In short:

```
$page = $page->getPage();
```

should have been replaced with

```
$page = $page->getGraphPage()->asArray();
```

Which will also give you the response as an array